# How do I fix the error I have when trying to call the method that contain KeyEventArgs e as argument

Tags: c#, .net, key, keyeventargs

Here is my code:

```
 public void Initialize()
    {
        //something here
        onKeyDown();
    }


    static void onKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Keys.H)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

and I get this error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'Main.onKeyDown(KeyEventArgs)'.

EDIT: Working With RAGE Plugin Hook, a library for gta v mod development.

Comment: Typically an event handler method is going to be attached to some control of the user interface, for instance, in your case, a user presses a key on the keyboard while interacting with a textbox in your application, this then calls the `onKeyDown` event handler method passing in the required `KeyEventArgs`. Since you are calling the method yourself in `Initialize` and not passing the parameter `e` of type `KeyEventArgs` this causes an error. You may want to read more:[Keydown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Also, your method signature is wrong if this is in the context of Windows Forms, as the method would take in not just the `KeyEventArgs` but also the `object` which triggered the event. Please add to your post as to what type of application you are working with.

Comment: I edited to post to be more clear!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you shouldn't do it, I'll let smarter people describe it.

Anyway, there's a way to call an event this way:

```cs
public void Initialize()
{
   onKeyDown((KeyEventArgs)System.EventArgs.Empty)
}
```

I would comment it but not enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet so posting as response.

You need to share what you are trying to do here. Why would you want to simulate a keypress? You could perhaps do something like this:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        //something here
        //onKeyDown();
DoStuff();
    }


    static void onKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Keys.H)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }

static void DoStuff(){
// DoStuff
}
```

To me it appears that you are trying to explicitly call an even handler which is not the purpose of event handlers. They are designed to be executed on if a certain user action or automated application action takes place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).